# Why the Symfony form is "not submitted" after data is correctly sent through AJAX?

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to sent a Symfony form through AJAX (AngularJS).

However, even if data is clearly sent, the form is said by Symfony to be "not submitted" (no error actually, but some debug show that `isSubmitted` returns `false`)

Here is a test on **FOSUserBundle registration form**.

EDIT: although pictures appear small, they are sufficiently resolved so that they are perfectly readable if displayed at their full size.

Here are the logs when I use a **standard submission from an HTTP form**:

[image: Symfony logs - HTTP form submission]

Here are the logs when I use **AJAX submission**:

[image: Symfony logs - AJAX submission]

- I have disabled CSRF token
- The method I use from AJAX is "post" so it should be ok since it is the default Symfony expects (and FOSUserBundle does not override that default AFAIK).
- Other forms (outside of FOSUserBundle scope) are correctly sent with AJAX

Would you have any idea on the matter? Any pointer? Or any other log I could check?

EDIT:

I use the [default FOSUserBundle registration controller](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php).

I almost use the [default FOSUserBundle registration form](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php), but I have added a (currently) empty child form which I'll need it further in the development.

```
namespace NONG\SecurityBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class UserRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {}

    public function getParent() {
        return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'nong_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Headers and data sent with the HTML form (NB. added a dot before star in Accept so that the coloration stays correct):

```
POST /server/web/testfosuser/register/ HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 229
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/.*;q=0.8
Origin: http://mywebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36         (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111             Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://mywebsite.com/server/web/testfosuser/register/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


fos_user_registration_form%5Bemail%5D=bidon%40bidon.com&
fos_user_registration_form%5Busername%5D=bidon&
fos_user_registration_form%5BplainPassword%5D%5Bfirst%5D=bidon&
fos_user_registration_form%5BplainPassword%5D%5Bsecond%5D=bidon
```

Headers sent with the AJAX request: (NB. added a dot before star in Accept so that the coloration stays correct):

```
POST /server/web/testfosuser/register HTTP/1.1
Host: mywebsite.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 229
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */.*
Origin: http://mywebsite.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://mywebsite.com/client/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

fos_user_registration_form%5Bemail%5D=bidonqdsfqsdf%40qsdf&
fos_user_registration_form%5Busername%5D=charles222&
fos_user_registration_form%5BplainPassword%5D%5Bfirst%5D=bidon&
fos_user_registration_form%5BplainPassword%5D%5Bsecond%5D=bidon
```

Comment: Can you show your form code, controller code and the request headers&body from both situation as captured by the chrome network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find the correction:

The correct URL is `...../register/` with a final `/` that I forgot when I did the AJAX request.

However, I'm not sure what are the mechanisms at stake here. The deepest I could go debuging (when using the wrong URL) was in `HttpFoundationRequestHandler`, where the `$request->getMethod()` call returned GET (instead of POST), thus not submitting the form.

Comment: From a quick look I believe is to prevent triggering of the "submit mechanism" when you are processing or just displaying the form in the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems and i changed the following inside of the controller:

```
$user    = new User();
$form    = $this->createForm(
    new UserRegistrationType(),
    $user,
    array(
        'attr' => array('novalidate' => 'novalidate'),
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('user_registration')
    )
 );
```

Turning of the html5 error bubbles and setting the action URL directly worked for me. If this is not working, show your JS code.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure, I have to replace the current `$form = $formFactory->createForm();` by your code? Can you explain a bit further why this works (not yet tested for me)?

Comment: I dont know if you just can do it, i dont know how your controller looks like. But if you want to use your code, just set the action path. By default it is just `action=""` and this was in my case a problem submitting it via ajax.